# How can I stop Android from synchronizing videos while still synchronizing photos?

Tags: sync

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 which is great for watching movies. I move them from my computer via USB to the "Movies" folder and it just works fine.

But one thing that I don't like is that the movie is synchronized. It gets automatically uploaded. I can see it on https://plus.google.com/photos/yourphotos. And I don't like that. How can I prevent Android from doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I have Samsung Galaxy Note II. In my phone I can configure the content synchronization in:
Settings / Cloud / Contents sync
There is independent sync setting for Pictures and Videos.